# Expo React Native: force virtual keyboard display when connecting to a physical keyboard/barecode scanner

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

Im developing a react native app with expo managed workflow.

I have a TextInput field in the app which I want it to accepts its input from a physical barcode scanner through bluetooth.

**The issue**: When connecting the barcode scanner through the bluetooth, the mobile identity it as the default input keyboard which makes the virtual/software keyboard to not open when focus on ****any**** input in the application.
But I want to force opening the software keyboard on focus to give the ability to the user to insert other information other than barcodes

Note: This issue is reproducible on ios and android both.

I tried to force opening the software keyboard using react native but nothing worked

Comment: share your code

Comment: @JuniusL Sorry code for what? Its a general behavior happening in react native for TextInput.